# How to set legend and title for multiple pie charts using chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, charts

My php page has multiple dynamic pie charts in which I wish to  display legend and title for each using chart.js

Here is my JS code:

```
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="django/static/js/Chart.min.js"></script>' );
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="extlib/jquery-min.js"></script>' );
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript">' );
    ?>
    function drawPie(canvasId,data){
    var ctx = $("#pie-canvas-" + canvasId).get(0).getContext("2d");

    var piedata = [];
    $.each(data,function(i,val){
    piedata.push({value:val.count,color:val.color,label:val.status});
    });

    new Chart(ctx).Pie(piedata);}
    <?php
    printf('</script>');
```

PHP code:

```
foreach ( $poolArray as $pool ) {//for multiple charts
     $data = statusPool($pool);
     echo '<td style="text-align: center;"><canvas id="pie-canvas-'
          . $canvasId
          . '" width="200" height="200"></canvas>';

     $data3 = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">drawPie('
          . $canvasId
          . ', '
          . $data3
          . ');</script>';
   }
```

Please suggest me for setting each pie chart a title and legend.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods - the `generateLegend()` method on the `new Chart(ctx).Pie(piedata)` object will return the HTML for the legend. You can then assign the return value to the `innerHTML` of some DOM element.

For example, add a `<div id="legend">` element next to the `<canvas>` element to hold the legend's HTML and then do something like:

```
var pc = new Chart(ctx).Pie(piedata);
document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = pc.generateLegend();
```

To add a title to your chart, just put an HTML heading (e.g. an `<h3>` element) in your HTML. I think Chart.js doesn't provide a title feature of its own.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.I tried out your code.But it simple display label names as text under pie chart. In my case the `label:value` is invisible.how to make it visible out side of each slice of chart?

Comment: You will also need some CSS to style the legend, each item is a list-item containing a colored span. See http://jsbin.com/zidujerefi/1/edit?html,output for an example.